# Textbox not displaing all the text?

Tags: asp.net, css, textbox, telerik, radtextbox

I have a telerik RadTextBox, in which i want to display one line, the problem the content is a little bit scrolling and don't display all the text, how can i fix it. thanks in advance.

Comment: Not ware of RadTextBox but have you changed the default size of your textbox?

Comment: yes... i set it to 16px and the font-size 10px... it works very well on chrome and IE but not on firefox

Comment: change it to something bigger and see how it works. Uses CSS `width` property if HTML `size` does not work. Size does not take px btw :) but characters

Comment: Is this an issue of your text running past the end of the text box or what?  If that is the problem then just make the box bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use textmode="singleline"

```
<telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="txtbox1" TextMode="SingleLine"></telerik:RadTextBox>
```